# Prove that the set of $X$ satisfies the equation $X- X_b - (1-v)\Delta t F(X) = 0$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

**Problem:** Let us consider the set $C$ contains $(X,v,w)$ satisfies the following constraints
\begin{align*}
    & X- X_b - (1-v) F(X) = 0 \tag{1a}\\
    & 1- (1-v) F'(X) - \varepsilon - w = 0 \tag{1b}\\
    & 0\le v \le v_0 \tag{1c} \\
    & w \ge 0 \tag{1d}
\end{align*}
where $X_b$ is a known value, and $F$ is Lipschitz and twice continuously differentiable. Prove that this set is bounded.

**My attempt:** Firstly, we can see that this set is nonempty (include $(X_b,1,\varepsilon)$). Let us take an element $(X,v,w)$ in the set $C$ arbitrarily. We can see easily that $v$ is bounded. In addition, we have
$$w = 1-(1-v)F'(X) - \varepsilon,$$
which shows that $w$ is bounded because $F'$ is bounded ($F$ is Lipschitz) and $v$ is bounded. Finally, we have to indicate $X$ is bounded. I have tried many ways but it may seem there is missing some assumptions to attain that.